# What is the best way to update a separate SQL table that contains information of one table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `Project` and a separate table called `Owners`.
In the `Project` table, it doesn't contain a column called owners, and the owner information is stored in the `Owners` table. The `Owners` table has a schema of `(id, user_id, proj_id)`

Due to this separation, I am having a trouble trying to update the list of owners from the frontend.

The flow in the frontend is like,

1. I fetch all the existing owners
2. I add an input to add new owners (can add/delete multiple onwers)
3. Submit (update with the most recent list)

I was thinking of deleting all the items in the `Owners` table with the `proj_id` and then just update the table with the most recent data.

However, I feel like this is inefficient. Especially when we have a huge number of owners, we cannot just remove everything add add the new ones every time we make an update.

I have to make an API to do this. Any thoughts or SQL query that makes this easier?

Comment: Don't you have a list of new user_ids? And user_ids that was removed? At the frontend.. Or do you just a list of user_ids for the proj_id?

Comment: I just have the list of the recent list of user_ids

Comment: How about you delete all the entries that are not in the list and then insert each from the list that is not in the table? You could use upsert depending on the constraints on your table.

Comment: Is this Many to Many relation From three table: `User` ; `Owners` and `Project` ?